# How can I safely kill a Whiptongue Bulborb?

Tags: pikmin-3

The Whiptongue Bulborb is giving me enormous amounts of trouble. Whenever I get into a fight with one I wind up using a large number of Pikmin, which just isn't acceptable. I try getting around to its back, but it moves fast enough that doing so is easier said than done. Even when I manage to get my Pikmin onto the Whiptongue it still manages to eat up my Pikmin, and when it shakes my Pikmin off I'll often lose one or two. I've tried calling them off before it shakes but that results in me doing almost no damage.

How can I safely, and quickly, dispose of the Whiptongue Bulborb?

[image: This guys a jerk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually approach a single Whiptongue Bulborb with your full group of pikmin safely:

Start by getting the Bulborb's attention, then move out it it's "patrol" range so it turns away from you. Then *constantly* batter it with Rock Pikmin from behind. The Bulborb will repeatedly attempt to shake off pikmin and it will take heavy damage from the rock pikmin's powerful through. You'll need at least ~20 rock pikmin to make the kill this way however. Safer strategies like using a small group of rock pikmin are preferable when you have small amounts of rock pikmin available.

Answer (score 2):

Like most of Pikmin 3's enemies, you can save the pikmin that are almost being eaten by dealing enough damage to the enemy before the eating animation finishes.  Your options for killing all variety of Bulborb:

1. Charging from behind with a squad of pikmin strong enough to kill in before the "wake up" animation finishes.  This is hard to achieve on the high HP bulborbs.
2. Throwing rock pikmin once the eating animation starts - don't need a large number, but extras allow you to fire away earlier and not be as precise with the whistling.
3. Approach from the front and aim for the weak point, the eyes.  Being in front of your target will limit the scattering of your pikmin when he shakes them off - most are thrown forward.  Keeping your target stationary and facing the same direction will make it much easier to accurately place your pikmin.  Even a squad of ~15 blue/yellow pikmin can safely take down a whiptounge with this method (it will be a tad slow).
4. A single bomb rock will do the trick.  For whiptounges that are awake, just be aware that they can eat the bomb and/or the pikmin trying to deliver it.  If they eat the bomb, they'll still die, but no surrounding enemies will be hurt.  If they eat the pikmin, it won't be spared when the bomb explodes.

Bomb rocks are definitely the way to go - in mission mode you will likely always have some available and whiptounges should be priority targets.  But number 3 is also very reliable.

In general, Pikmin 3's enemies are much easier if you use the wiimote + nunchuck for precision aiming.  Being able to land pikmin precisely and whistling back only pikmin who are idle or in danger is critical for having a no-death play-through or mission mode hi-scores.

Answer (score 1):

Small groups of [Rock Pikmin](http://pikmin.wikia.com/wiki/Rock_Pikmin) seem to be effective at safely disposing of the Whiptongue Bulborbs, assuming they are in their flower form. A small group of flowered Rock Pikmin are maneuverable enough to be able to avoid most of the Bulborbs attacks. They also deal enough damage in a single throw so you can safely get a hit off with multiple Rock Pikmin and then have them retreat from battle before being attacked. Using this method I was able to take down a Whiptongue with 5 Rock Pikmin. I did lose two Pikmin in the process, but with a bit more practice that number should be reduced to zero.

Comment: This is pretty similar to safe strategies with small numbers of Purple pikmin in Pikmin 2. Rock pikmin seem to work like somewhat nerfed Purples.

Comment: @BenBrocka I'd say the fact that Rock move at regular movement speed makes them superior to Purples.

Answer (score 1):

Bomb Rocks are the way to go against any Bulborb. Besides the fact that the Bulbear only instantly dies if it eats the rock, I'd say Bomb Rocks or Rock Pikmin will work. (aim for the eyes.)